# Redirect_url_mismatch error with Backendless google easy login on Android

Tags: java, authentication, google-authentication, backendless

I created an App on the backendless platform.  I entered google OAuth 2.0 client IDs and secret key into the the backendless dev console and then downloaded the generated code in IDe format Android Studio.

When I run the application on my phone, I am getting the following error:

> Google 400: that's an error
>
> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> A native application: appname
>
> Request Details
>    scope=email
>   response_type=code
>   redirect_uri=https://api.backendless.com
>   state=GUID
>   client_id=auth2.0id string
>
> that's all we know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to configure Backendless Google Login: Easy and SDK. I am sorry that I did not provide screen shot.

**Get OAuth Client ID and Secret**

1. Log into google dev console - https://console.developers.google.com
2. Create Project
3. Click on Library, Click on Google+ API and Enable
4. Click on Credentials, Click on Create Credentials
5. From Dropdown select OAuth client Id
6. Select Web Application
7. Provide Name - this is just friendly has not used
8. Under Restrictions heading, enter into Authorized redirect URIs field
   https://api.backendless.com/users/social/googleplus/authorize
9. Click create button (I had to click twice)
10. Copy Client ID to note pad (XXXXXXXXXXXX-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY.apps.googleusercontent.com)
11. Copy Client Secret to note pad

**Configure Backendless**

1. Create App
2. On the App Setting tab
3. Under Social Settings
4. In the Google Plus ID field paste the OAuth Client ID
5. in the Google Plus Secret field past the OAuth Client Secret

**Easy login Demo**

1. From App Setting
2. At the bottom select Generate Code
3. Select IDE
4. In the Registration and User section, select Google Plus Login
5. At the bottom click on Download Project

**SDK login Demo**

1. Download Samples from Github
2. Open Project
3. Delete backendless.jar from lib folder
4. Add to build.gradle dependency section
   compile 'com.backendless:backendless:3.0.20.1'
5. Update Defaults.java file for constants APPLICATION_ID (Application ID) and SECRET_KEY (Android Secret Key) from the Backendless Dev Console application settings screen fields.
6. Update LoginFragment.java file for constant SERVER_CLIENT_ID using backendless app setting Google Plus ID field (which is the OAuth Client ID from the Google Dev Console)
7. Run

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

```
redirect_uri=https://apibackendless.com
```

And the `redirect_uri` has to be `https://api.backendless.com` (notice the dot after **api**).

Comment: Please change this to a comment instead of an answer. The typo has been fixed.

Comment: @BarryMSIH do you still receive the same error after fixing a typo?

Comment: The orinal error contained the correct url. I think the problem was I did not know you had to configure google with the authorized redirect.